# How to filter events from Kafka Stream based on its JSON Contents

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Kafka Streams to read from a topic in my cluster, and I want to filter messages based on its JSON contents, i.e.:

JSON Format:

```
{
   "id": 1 
   "timestamp": "2019-04-21 12:53:18", 
   "priority": "Medium", 
   "name": "Sample Text",
   "metadata": [{
      "metric_1": "0", 
      "metric_2": "1", 
      "metric_3": "2"
   }]
}
```

I want to read the messages from an input topic (let's call it "input-topic"), filter them (let's assume I only want messages which priority is "Low"), then aggregate these, and send them to another topic ("filtered-topic")

I don't have that much code other than creating the stream itself and its configurations. I'm thinking there must be something about the Serdes that I need to configure but I'm not sure how. I also tried using JSON deserializer but I couldn't get it to work.

First of all, is this even possible? If so, what would be the correct course of action?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `then aggregate`? do you want to aggregate by time?

Comment: It is possible. You need to read the messages, deserialize it to your custom object, then have the logic of filtering based on the field of that custom object and then publish it back to another topic.

Comment: You can either use spring's Kafka library, or Apache's Kafka library or even spring cloud library.

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi By "aggregate" I mean send the filtered messages to a separate topic, that's it

Comment: then you need to use `filter` from streams DSL:
`streamsBuilder.stream("source-topic-name", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), yourAnalyticsClassSerde)).filter((key, value) -> "Low".equals(value.getPriority)).to("destination-topic-name");`. Stream will deserialize message to object  using serde, for that you need to create it (e.g. using `JsonSerde` from spring-kafka).

Comment: There are many examples online: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi I'm not understanding the later part of the filtering, mainly the value.getPriority. is that supposed to be a function I create?

Answer (score 1):

You can build stream from topic.

```
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    // key value type here is both String for me and update based on cases
    KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream("input-topic");

    source.filter(new Predicate<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(String s, String s2) {
            // your filter logic here and s and s2 are key/value from topic
            // In your case, s2 should be type of your json Java object
            return false;
        }
    }).groupBy(new KeyValueMapper<String, String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(String key, String value) {
            // your group by logic
            return null;
        }
    }).count().toStream().to("new topic");
```

Comment: I seem to be getting some compilation errors trying to make this work:
"wrong number of type arguments; required 1"
"no interface expected here"
"method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

Mainly on the filter part

Comment: I think you need kafka-stream dependency

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>